# Android Calling Webservice Error

Tags: android, web-services

Hello in my android application when i am accessing webservice of login in android app it successfully runs on emulator but after installing it on real device it gives error unfortunately stopped application how to solve this error

here is My code

```
private void login(final String username, String password) {

        class LoginAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

            private Dialog loadingDialog;

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                loadingDialog = ProgressDialog.show(LoginActivity.this, "Please wait", "Loading...");
            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                String uname = params[0];
                String pass = params[1];
                InputStream is = null;
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mobile", uname));
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", pass));
                String result = null;

                try {
                    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("https://myurl/soapapi/login.php");
                    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

                    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

                    is = entity.getContent();

                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8"), 8);
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                    String line = null;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                    }
                    result = sb.toString();
                } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return result;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                String s = result.trim();
                String[] t_id = s.split(" ");
                String status = t_id[1].toString();
                loadingDialog.dismiss();
                if (s.equalsIgnoreCase(status)) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                    //intent.putExtra(USER_NAME, username);
                    finish();
                    startActivity(intent);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid User Name or Password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }

        LoginAsync la = new LoginAsync();
        la.execute(username, password);

    }


}
```

Comment: you should look into the LogCat, and find error stacktrace there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)

Comment: I have also tried this option but it runs proper on emulator and when i have attached real device for debugging there is a null response from webservice

Comment: you should have mention that. Show the code and URL you are connecting to.

Comment: I suspect you trying to connect to local URL, which doesn't work on real device 'cause you are not in same network

Comment: is your `myurl` an IP address?

Comment: no there is a website name

Comment: It seems like URL issue, make sure about it....